# dropdown touch area increase its not touchable properly

Tags: react-native, dropdown

dropdown touch area increase its not touchable properly is it possible we can give touch area to view open dropdown 
i am using material dropdown

```js
 <Dropdown
  //label="1"
  value={pickerSelectedQty}
  data={data}
  onChangeText={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {}}
  containerStyle={{
    width: 240,
    height: 40
  }}
  inputContainerStyle={{
    borderBottomColor: "transparent",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginVertical: -24
  }}
  containerStyle={{
    width: "87%"
  }}
  overlayStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
  pickerStyle={false}
  style={styles.pickerGreyed}
/>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Format and word your question better. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26252750).

Comment: its basically i have create a View inside that i added dropdown so i want touch should be on full View area